# How to set maximum execution time for KDB query?

Tags: kdb

Especially when querying a remote KDB instance, having a typo in your query which causes it to take hours instead of seconds is a pain -- since the server is remote, I can't even access it to kill the KDB instance.

So I have wondering if there is some way to specify a maximum execution time?

**Edit:**

I'm looking for a way to do this from the client side on a per-query basis. Some queries might legitimately take hours, but others shouldn't take more than 10 secs. A hard limit on the server side wouldn't help this.

Comment: If your KDB instance is hanging, you can just get the PID for that process and send a signal using UNIX to interrupt the process?

`>ps -aef | grep <process patern>`
`>kill -SIGINT <PID>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\T 5
```

or starting kdb with

```
q -T 5
```

Would set a max 5 second time out on user queries.

You can send a SIGINT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal that has the same effect as pressing control-C which will attempt to stop a command being processed. Not all q code supports interrupts.

One way of doing this is having two q processes, one of which is just used to send linux kill interrupt signals.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do this from the client side on a per-query basis? Some queries might legitimately take hours, but others shouldn't take more than 10 secs. A hard limit on the server side isn't going to help this.

Comment: In response to your statement "drop the connection to cancel a query", after dropping the connection I cannot reconnect, presumably because the server is still busy with the previous query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to forward query via own process:

```
  \T 3
  h:hopen `::3000
  0(h;({system "sleep 2";x+1};5))
6
  0(h;({system "sleep 4";x+1};5))
'stop
```