# Timeout in kdb+ for function

Tags: kdb

I have a function dummyFun:{[x;y] show x+y} in kdb+.

but after calling it takes too much time to execute. I want to apply timeout for this function execution. Like if it doesn't return anything it should throw an error timeout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23011237/9364415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set client query timeouts with `-T x` / `system"T x"`

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/cmdline/#-t-timeout

If you want to timeout your own function within the q console you can use the 0 handle when calling your code/function:

```
// eg
\T 1
0"system\"sleep 2\"
'stop

// with (func;params)
0 (dummyFun;x;y)
```